# Postfix mail server - Gmail integration

Tags: 20.04, postfix, gmail

I've setup a postfix mail server. I had an issue with some emails getting rejected but managed to fix it. I have been looking at solutions and had found one option to use Gmail as the SMTP relayhost. However, as per Google, they won't allow less secure apps to connect and send emails after May 2022.

I wanted to ask if you know any other similar service as Gmail or even if there's a way so I could still keep using Gmail.

It's only a small project so I'd prefer a free solution like Gmail but will consider paying for the right solution. I want to log all the outgoing emails for auditing purposes.

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: "However, as per Google, they won't allow less secure apps to connect and send emails after May 2022." Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is stated here:  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy= but, I am having an issue seeing exactly where SMTP will no longer be supported.  They aren't very clear about what is and what isn't going to be turned off.

Comment: @waltinator - I forgot to add - it's 20.04. Is there any solution available?

Comment: @Terrance thanks very much.

Comment: I use 2 Factor Auth for my Google, and when I setup my SMTP relay with them it forced me to use an app password instead of my password.  Looking at the list of the third-party security standards it appears to pretty much cover all in the list, where the first listed item is kind of a toss up, but the other 3 are how it is setup.  If I try to use my normal password, it will reject my sending of emails stating the password is incorrect.  Come May 30th we will see if Google shuts off my SMTP sending.

Comment: @Terrance I also use the app password feature for my mail relay. Reading the link, I am hopeful that will still work but one never knows with Google. Thanks again.

Comment: Most ISP provide free e-mail accounts with their subscriptions. you could give a call to yours and ask. At least you could get one for few bucks and use your ISP servers as relayhost

Answer (score 2):

Go to the security options of the sending account:
https://myaccount.google.com/security

Activate 2FA (if you haven't already) and then select App Passwords:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Create your custom service (you can choose any name) and it will generate a special password.

Enter that password in the sasl_passwd file

Comment: OK thanks I'll try that.

Comment: that totally saved me ! my postfix setup had stopped working due to the change in google policy last month.  Thanks !